# Seeking for a way to use my Android phone as a computer speaker without any additional software

Tags: windows-7, audio, android, speakers, xiaomi

Recently, my computer speakers stopped working, and I'm considering using my Android phone as a substitute. However, all the solutions I came across involve using 3rd party software that requires Wi-Fi and are freemium options. My PC runs on Windows 7, and I have a Xiaomi Poco X3 phone with Android 12. Are there any alternative methods to accomplish this without depending on additional software?

Comment: [AudioRelay](https://audiorelay.net/) is free ([link](https://www.makeuseof.com/android-phone-speaker-pc/)). Do you have WiFi?

Comment: No, I don't have.

Comment: You can use AudioRelay in wired mode. It can be run through USB connection to the phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[AudioRelay](https://audiorelay.net/) is free
and can be used without WiFi.

See the AudioRelay support article
[USB connectivity](https://docs.audiorelay.net/usb):

> **USB tethering**
>
> USB tethering is a way to share your phone's connection to your PC.
> Activating it will allow AudioRelay to send audio directly through a
> USB cable.
>
> **How to**
>
> - Connect your Android device to your PC via a USB cable
> - Enable USB tethering in your phone's settings
> - Your PC will take a few moments to configure the connection
> - Go back to AudioRelay, you can now click on the new server entry!

The above article contains screenshots of the settings to
be tweaked.

For more information see the article
[How to Use Your Android Phone as a Speaker for Your Windows, Mac, or Linux Computer](https://www.makeuseof.com/android-phone-speaker-pc/).